# How get GNU screen to create unique enviroment variables in each screen separately

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, gnu-screen

I currently run a bunch of scripts in python and shell scripts in a server.

I am running them using GNU screen so that they can run in parallel.

```
counter=0

while read -r word; do
    counter=$(( counter + 1))
    screen -dmS $counter sh -c "python3 script1.py $word;exec bash"
done </home/user/Documents/wordlist.txt

counter=$(( counter + 1))
screen -dmS $counter sh -c "python3 script2.py;exec bash"

counter=$(( counter + 1))
screen -dmS $counter sh -c "python3 script3.py;exec bash"
```

this word list is 5 words long so it creates 5 processes.
then there are 2 more processes after that for a total of 7 processes. each screen is named screen 1-7 based on the counter.

How do I get each screen process to create an environment number and so that it can remember what process number it was, based on the counter, so that when it ends I can use it for something else after that.

So that if I was in the screen number 6 I could type out $PROCESSNUMBER to recall that this was number 6. Preferably, I could run the same command in each screen.

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @anarchy: I don't use _screen_ anymore, but from the [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Environment) I conclude that _screen_ sets the variable `WINDOW` to identify, which screen you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a shell command there, so just export a variable:

```
screen -dmS $counter sh -c "export PROCESSNUMBER=$counter; python3 script3.py;exec bash"
```

Comment: i havent tried it yet but so when i access a certain screen each one will have a different PROCESSNUMBER yes ?